# Is there an equivalent to "Fields Virology" for Bacteria?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I've gotten a staggering amount of use out of my copy of *Fields Virology* as a general reference for "getting me up to speed" on whatever pathogen I'm currently looking at. I don't know of a similar type of reference for bacteria, but I only became aware of *Fields* as I was moving *out* of the field, rather than into it, so it's possible I've simply never heard of a suitable reference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I might as well give this as an answer: the closest analog to Fields for bacteriology that I'm aware of are the two Bergey's manuals: [*Bergey's Manual of Systematic Bacteriology*](http://www.springer.com/series/4157), and [*Bergey's Manual of Determinative Bacteriology*](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=jtMLzaa5ONcC). They deal with taxonomy and identification of bacteria (and even cyanobacteria and archaeans), with some emphasis on the medically important classes.

Answer (score 5):

The Manual of Clinical Microbiology from ASM is the bible we use in our Micro lab. It's often our first reference. There are a lot of other useful books in the ASM eStore.

[ASM eStore](http://estore.asm.org/viewItemDetails.asp?ItemID=1021)